# How to create Watermark on .doc extension files using Java (Apache poi)

Tags: java, apache-poi, .doc, apache-poi-4

I am trying to create a watermark on .doc file and .docx file, I achieved the .docx extension watermarking using the apache-poi 4. But I Cannot rewrite the code for the .doc extension using the same approch.

I tried to swap XWPFDocument with HWPFDocument for the .doc extension but it wont give me the headerfooter policy object for creating watermark.
Below is the code snippet that worked for .docx extension

```
XWPFDocument xDoc = new XWPFDocument(stream);
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy xFooter = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(xDoc);
xFooter.createWatermark("watermark-text");
```

Is there any way to achieve .doc extension file watermarking using apahce-poi ??

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248276/add-watermark-in-word-document-using-apache-poi

Comment: Thanks @Sambit . I tried that answer but it only worked for .docx extension.

Comment: After getting, .docx, try to rename or convert it to doc and check whether it works or not.

Comment: I don't believe that this will be possible using `HWPF` of `apache poi`. The `H` in all of the binary `OLE2` file format classes of `apache poi` stands for horrible. But the `*.doc` file format is the horriblest of all horrible file formats. And so `HWPF` classes are currently only in scratchpad: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_0/src/scratchpad/src/org/apache/poi/hwpf/.

Comment: Thanks @Axel Richter . Is there any other opensource library is avialable for adding watermark on .doc file?